# Как запустить скрипт на стороннем сервере?

Tags: php, javascript

Есть мой сервер А и сторонний сервер B.
Я хочу выполнить js скрипт на сервере B и получить обратно html после выполнения этого скрипта (или даже лучше конкретный `div` из этого html'a).
Как можно это сделать, может быть, существуют готовые библиотеки? 
Интересуют решения и на js, и на php. Вариант с инжектингом через расширение браузера не интересует.

---

**Обновление из комментариев**:

Пользователь вообще не подозревает о наличии сервера Б. Приведу такой пример: пользователь жмет на ссылку на сервере А, и в это время php или js скрипт в, можно сказать, фоновом режиме, открывает у себя страницу на сервере Б, выполняет там скрипт (допустим, скрипт нажатия на кнопку, которая открывает на странице сервера Б всплывающее окно, в котором показывается определенный текст), и пользователь видит на сервере А текст из этого окна.

Comment: Можно получить документ html на стороне клиента и выполнить поиск нужного div'а

Comment: Вы хотите выполнить js скрипт, который находится на сервере А, на сервере Б? Или выполнить скрипт, который находится на сервере Б на этом же сервере Б?

Comment: @VenZell первый вариант (выполнить js скрипт, который находится на сервере А, на сервере Б)

Comment: А действия какого рода должен выполнять с содержимым сервера Б этот скрипт?

Comment: @VenZell допустим, элементарно, клик на каком то элементе на странице сервера Б

Comment: @ilyaspark, для начала стоит определиться: вы действительно имеете в виду _сервер Б_? или речь идет о выполнении чего-то в _окне бразуера клиента_, открывшего страницу на сервере Б.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev нет, пользователь вообще не подозревает о наличии сервера Б. Приведу такой пример - пользователь жмет на ссылку на сервере  А, и в это время php или js скрипт в, можно сказать, фоновом режиме, открывает у себя страницу на сервер Б, выполняет там скрипт (допустим скрипт нажатия на кнопку, которая открывает на странице сервера Б всплывающее окно, в котором показывается определенный текст), и пользователь видит на сервере А текст из этого окна

Comment: Думаю вот это все стоит добавить в сам вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужен headless-браузер, например, [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org).
Для него есть обертка на PHP: [PHP PhantomJS](https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs).

PhantomJS позволит выполнить произвольный javascript-код на указанной странице. Принцип действия схож с действием расширений в браузере. Нужный вам скрипт будет включен и выполнен в контексте целевой страницы.

Вот пара статей по этому поводу:
[Пишем парсер сайтов с использованием PhantomJS](http://blog.luchnikov.ru/programming/phantomjs/)
[Знакомство с PhantomJS на практике](http://usefuldevops.ru/blog/2013/08/23/znakomstvo-s-phantomjs-na-praktikie/)

Comment: Это то, что мне нужно, огромное спасибо!